# Installing Revolution Analytics broke R and I can't fix it

Tags: 14.04, r

So I installed (and quickly un-installed Revolution analytics's [RRO with MKL](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/rro/installation/#tab-mJlhge6Nhg-2)) following their instructions (e.g. using the `.deb` and removing using `dpkg`).

Now, I want to use the default/standard R again, so I do:

```
> R
```

and get:

```
The program 'R' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

Ok. So I type:

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

but then, I get:

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> r-base-core is already the newest version.
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
> ```

But when I type:

```
> R
```

I get again:

```
The program 'R' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

How to get `R` back?

Comment: what does `which R` give you?

Comment: nothing! (the content of this parenthesis is to hit the character limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, fixed thus (for future reference):

Remove `R` completly and *then* install it back:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-core
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-dev

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```